# How do I redirect_to a newly rendered page (not cached) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, redirect

In Rails 3 (with Chrome), I set a flash, call redirect_to, and so send the browser back to a page which the user has been on before.

However, Chrome does not  render this page; rather, Chrome takes it from the cache. This means, for example, that the flash is not rendered.

I could add a random param to the URL to make sure the cache is not used, but this is clumsy.

How do I make sure that the page I am redirecting to is re-rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways i can think of to do this: `meta http-equiv` tags or http headers.

**Method A) meta http-equiv**

Add the following to the head section of your template.

```
<% if @prevent_caching %>
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
<% end %>
```

then, in any controller action you can say `@prevent_caching = true` before rendering the page.

This seems a bit clumsy, and i believe `meta http-equiv` can be unreliable.  Hence...

**Method B) http headers.**
This is a much more direct and reliable way of telling the browser not to cache:
see [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

I would put them in a protected method in your ApplicationController, which will let you call it from any other controller (since they all inherit from this)

```
#in app/controllers/application.rb
protected
def prevent_browser_caching
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' # HTTP 1.1.
  response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache' # HTTP 1.0.
  response.headers['Expires'] = '0' # Proxies.
end
```

Then, it's like before except you call the method instead of setting a variable.

```
#in the controller where you don't want the response to be cached
prevent_browser_caching
```